# Laravel Route gives Object not found error

Tags: laravel, rest, api, routes

So i had a route to create a post that was like http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create and now I am trying to delete the word *create* completely  and have my route as http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ the problem is when i put nothing after the (/) I get Object not found Error, but when i put anything even one letter after the (/) it works.

Is not it allowed for a POST method to be used where its url ends with a slash? I'm confused

Comment: Can you post your routes file within your question

Comment: If using `Route::resource()` to create your routes, removing `create` will not work. Using resource uses the convention of these routes to be clear about the intention. `/posts` in this case, would be used to show all posts, `/posts/1` to show a post with the id of `1`.

Comment: No i'm not using `Route:resource()` , i'm using my own routes.

`Route::post('/posts/', 'PostController@create');` which was before:

`Route::post('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, that was silly, the problem was that i'm adding a / at the end of the route while it should be /posts and that is it, no / after posts